# Learning JavaScript used in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

Now I have started working in JavaScript that is used in SharePoint. I would need to perform basic operations like retrieve list items and display them as per the requirement. I am familiar with JavaScript and I have used in .NET. Please provide me some references from where I can learn this.

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dn833469.aspx "MSDN") is best place to learn stuffs related with SharePoint development, you will get working demo functions there.

Comment: Please elaborate your question so I provide a solution as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/Hh185007(v=office.14).aspx) is always a good point to start.

You can also check my [blog](https://blog.afrait.com/category/javascript/) and there the javascript category.

The Topics are:

- [PDF Preview in library / hover-panel (en)](https://blog.afrait.com/pdf-preview-in-library-hover-panel-en/)
- [Slice Description without cutting words (en)](https://blog.afrait.com/slice-description-without-cutting-words-en/)
- [Color Calender and Icons in 10 easy Steps (de)](https://blog.afrait.com/color-calender-and-icons-in-10-easy-steps-de/)
- [Progress bar in task list (en)](https://blog.afrait.com/progress-bar-in-task-list-en/)
- [Traffic light column in custom list (en)](https://blog.afrait.com/traffic-light-column-in-custom-list-en/)
- [How to upload .js files and link it to a list in 9 Steps (de/en)](https://blog.afrait.com/how-to-upload-js-files-and-link-it-to-a-list-9-steps/)
- [Highlight rows in list with CSR (de)](https://blog.afrait.com/highlight-rows-in-list-with-csr-de/)

Sorry for advertising my blog that much :)

Answer (score -1):

The following link will help to perform basic List Operations using [Client Object model and Javascript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201(v=office.15).aspx).